# How can we generate year wise day report by using while loop or CTE or any other method in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I tried this

```
SELECT 
    Day = DATEPART(DAYOFWEEK, dateColumnName),
    Date = dateColumnName
```

but the output looks like this:

```
JAN 1 2020  TO DEC 31 2020

Result
========
2020/01/01
2020/01/02
.
.
.
2020/12/21
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a calendar table which is strongly recommended, you can use an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2020-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2020-12-31'

Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)+1) 
       D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
```

**Returns**

```
D
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-04
2020-01-05
...
2020-12-31
```

Update CTE

```
Declare @StartDate date = '2020-01-01' 
Declare @EndDate   date = '2020-12-31'

;with CTE AS
(
  Select [Date]= @StartDate
  Union All
  Select (DateAdd(DAY,1,[Date]))
   From  CTE
   Where [Date] < @EndDate
) 
SELECT *  
 From  CTE
 option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: what is meant by calendar table and can we do the same procedure using CTE?

Comment: @krish A calendar table is just that... a table of dates with additional attributes.  Yes this can be done in a CTE, but this approach is more performant than a loop and/or a recursive cte.   To be clear, master..spt_values is just a known table, you can use any table of adequate size/rows.

Comment: how can we do it through CTE,could you let me know,so it would be helpul how cte works.

Comment: @krish Added a CTE

Comment: Thanks John Cappelleti and sorry for the inconvience,i also want to know it by using  while loop.can i know how we will do by using while loop

Comment: @krish Nope, I won't do it.  Loops should be avoided where and when possible

Comment: no problem,thanks man,it helped me a lot

Comment: @krish Always happy to help